# Java midi Sequencer - change program works only on channel 0

Tags: java, midi, javasound

Here is an attempt to produce midi-sound via javax.sound.midi

```
ShortMessage first = new ShortMessage();
first.setMessage(ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE, 1, 7, 0); // changing instrument here
MidiEvent changeInstrument = new MidiEvent(first, 1);
track.add(changeInstrument);
 
ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
a.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 1, 44, 127);
MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 2);
track.add(noteOn);
 
ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
a.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 1, 44, 127);
MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 32);
track.add(noteOff);
 
player.setSequence(seq);
player.start();
```

Problem is that instrument is not changed ("Acoustic grand piano" is played independently of chosen number).

However I found at first that all works perfect if channel number is 0 rather than 1. Later I found more confusing thing - all works perfect even if program change is called on channel 0 while notes are played on any other channel.

I'm testing it on Windows with (I suppose) program synthesizer.

Could somebody enlighten me about reasons for such a suspicious behavior of API?

I've found old bug filed, but I am not aware whether it is related:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4425843

Here are also threads about which I could not understand whether they are related or not:
[Setting instrument channels using the javax.sound.midi package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828820/setting-instrument-channels-using-the-javax-sound-midi-package)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).